# How to export data to an excel file from multiple pages on a website build in .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, export

My web application is build using in asp.net MVC. I am getting data from multiple db sources. I want to facilitate the export of data retrieved using multiple controllers, displayed on multiple pages, to an excel file. Is it possible to do that? If yes, then can someone point to a resource? All I can find is to export data from one page or from one controller. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is, create a Action method which is responsible to collect data from all the sources. You may have various services that retrieve data from different data sources.

The key is to collect all the data in one object and then hand it over to export-to-excel library.

Comment: thanks SBirthare, I'll try your suggestion and let know.

Answer (score 0):

You can build single action that represents report you want which comprises all required data for your report and then export it in way that your found for "one page".

Comment: Funny how similar thoughts getting typed at the same time in different part of the world ;)